# General Relativity and antimatter: Would antigravity of antimatter really disprove GR?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, antimatter

I understand that this may be a naive question but my understanding is that GR predicts that antiparticles should be affected by gravity just as regular matter is. But does GR discuss how a massive (say planet-sized) chunk of antimatter would curve space?

Comment: There hasn't been any experimental study of gravitational interaction of antimatter, even at the atomic level. But the electron-positron annihilation would strongly suggest that antimatter would have positive mass and behave the same way as matter

Comment: i know that it is problematic to accumulate enough antimatter to even watch it fall but even harder (much, much harder) to find out if a planet made from antimatter attracts matter -- does this annihilation suggest that also a large amount of antimatter curves space just like matter does?

Comment: So far, experiments on anti-hydrogen indicate it behaves the same as hydrogen.

Comment: In pair production, both electron and position have *positive* energy. Gravity couples to energy.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9375/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

Antimatter has positive observed mass and energy, so the prediction in GR that it would curve space exactly as does matter is quite unambiguous, as is the prediction that it would follow geodesics exactly like matter.

Comment: But a question, if we reversed all charge-like properties in say, the Kerr-Newman metric, what effect would that be on gravitational potential? was there any theoretical studies of this?

Comment: @AGawish The KN solution with charge $Q$ and $-Q$ have identical properties.