# Is there a gravitational force among antiparticles?

Tags: gravity, antimatter

Is there a gravitational force between antiparticles?
For example,  between two antiprotons. Do the antiprotons repluse each other?

Comment: There's gravitational force to anything that has mass/energy/momentum. Also gravitational force is always attractive.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9371/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/139545/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Has the gravitational interaction of antimatter ever been examined experimentally?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/139545/)

Comment: You'll rarely see gravity when dealing with particle physics.

Answer (score 2):

Because antiparticles have mass, they will necessarily experience the attractive force of gravity. That force will be extremely tiny compared to the electrostatic force of repulsion between two antiprotons.