# Gravitational interaction between antimatter particles

Tags: particle-physics, gravity, antimatter, matter

Is there some positron-positron collision experiments?

Is the gravitational interaction between antimatter particles the same as between ordinary matter particles?

Comment: Particle accelerators can’t test the gravitational interaction between the colliding particles; it’s much too weak.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_interaction_of_antimatter

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/139545/2451 and links therein.